# What are the problems with the best approximation ratio achieved by algorithm returning uniformly random solution?

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, approximation-algorithms

> What are the problems with the best known approximation ratio achieved by an algorithm returning a uniformly random solution?

I know one such example for permutation flow shop problem $F|perm|C_{max}$: in the paper "[Tight Bounds for Permutation Flow Shop Scheduling](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=14978066871570961423&hl=en&as_sdt=2001)" Viswanath Nagarajan and Maxim Sviridenko proved that random sequence of jobs have guarantee $2\sqrt{min\{m,n\}}$ ($m$-number of machines and $n$ - number of jobs) which is the best known currently.

Comment: Max3SAT? ------

Comment: AFAIK, Max3SAT fits here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For constraint satisfaction problems, the property of having no better approximation algorithm than random assignment is known as **approximation resistance**.

This is has been studied by several works in the last few years, with some results based on $P\neq NP$ and other more general results based on the unique games conjecture. A good source for this is [Per Austrin's thesis](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~austrin/papers/thesis.pdf).

Comment: that is neat. I had no idea that such a concept existed.

Answer (score 12):

According to [Guraswami et al, FOCS '08](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/FOCS.2008.51), the unique games conjecture would imply that there is no approximation algorithm for the maximum acyclic edge set of a digraph significantly better than the one that randomly permutes the vertices and includes an edge when it goes from an earlier to a later vertex in the permutation (with approximation ratio 1/2).

Answer (score 10):

In his paper "[Optimal Approximation for the Submodular Welfare Problem in the Value Oracle Model](http://www.math.princeton.edu/~jvondrak/data/submod-value.pdf)" Jan Vondrak asserts:

> "Interestingly, in the special case of Submodular Welfare with $n$ equal players, the optimal $(1 − \frac{1}{e})$-approximation is in fact obtained by a uniformly random solution."